# Why Remix is telling me to use "pure"?

Tags: error, visibility, pure, scope

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract enumTesting{
    enum frenchFriesSize {large, medium, small}
    frenchFriesSize choice;
    frenchFriesSize constant defaultChoice = frenchFriesSize.medium;
    
    
    function setSmall() public {
        choice = frenchFriesSize.small;
    }
    
    function getChoice() public view returns(frenchFriesSize){
        return choice;
    }
    
    function getDefault() public view returns(uint){
        return uint(defaultChoice);
    }
    
}
```

Remix is sugesting me to change the getDefault function to "pure", but isn't reading the variable "defaultChoice" from outside of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remix recommends to declare the function as `pure` because `defaultChoice` isn't a variable. The compiler does inline constant in the code so they don't use space in storage.